# Binding for inserting new list item in Markdown

Tags: markdown, spacemacs

I'm looking for a way of emulating the behavior of Sublime's [`MarkdownEditing`](https://github.com/SublimeText-Markdown/MarkdownEditing) package in Spacemacs. To start, here are two features of `MarkdownEditing` that I would like to implement in Spacemacs.

1. At the end of a list item, hitting `RET` inserts a new list item at the same level as the previous one.
2. Pressing `TAB` in a blank list item will indent (and, optionally, change bullet type).

I have no sense of where to begin trying to implement this in Spacemacs. Any pointers would be most welcome.

(I guess the more general question is: how to configure key bindings for insert mode for a specific language?)

Answer (score 0):

This is a very old question but I found it before finding the answer, so thought I'd add an answer

### 1. Adding list items

To add a new item at the same level you do `SPC m l i`. Using `,` is a shortcut for `SPC m`, so you could do `, l i` instead. `MET-RET` also works (try `ctrl+alt+m` if it doesn't work).

### 2. Indenting blocks

`SPC m >` to indent region, `SPC m <` to outdent region. This can be shortened to `, >` and `, <`.

[This page](https://develop.spacemacs.org/layers/+lang/markdown/README.html#key-bindings) contains the full list of shortcuts for Markdown mode in Spacemacs.